# Возможно ли собрать библиотеки qt из исходников под 64 битную платформу в Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

Я работал с библиотеками `Qt`, которые собрал из исходников, в Windows 7.
Собирал со следующей конфигурацией:

```
.\configure.bat -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc2015 …
```

Возможна ли сборка библиотек `Qt` без cygwin и mingw. Что-то типа такого:

```
.\configure.bat -debug-and-release -platform win-x64-msvc2015 …
```

Comment: посмотрите видео, возможно поможет  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6Mg8FpFPS8&t=4s

Comment: Спасибо. Я получил ответ : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046684/how-to-build-64-bit-qt-libraries-without-cygwin-and-mingw-in-windows-7?noredirect=1 . Как закрыть вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Все было из-за того, что я не знал, что в 64 разрядной Windows 7 по умолчанию собирается 32 разрядные библиотеки Qt (или у меня где-то стоят настройки на 32 битные версии).

Для сборки 64 битных библиотек необходимо запустить `vcvarsall.bat` с опцией `x64`, а уже после этого, без указания платформы, собирать Qt библиотеки.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x64`

`.\configure.bat -debug-and-release …`

Ответ получил здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046684/how-to-build-64-bit-qt-libraries-without-cygwin-and-mingw-in-windows-7?noredirect=1